# Making a quiz with Java using arrays. Need pointers with grading answers

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

This is for a class. I'm having trouble figuring out how to best compare the user input with the array answerkey and consequently grade the answers given. I tried searching for a while but wasn't able to find what I needed, so any pointers would be much appreciated!

The prompt for the exercise is:

Write a DMV program that grades the written portion of the driver's license exam. It should have 20 multiple choice questions. It should ask the user to enter the student’s answers for each of the 20 questions, which should be stored in another array. After the student’s answer have been entered, the program should display a message indicating whether the student passed or failed the exam.( A student must correctly answer 15 of the 20 questions to pas the exam). It should then display the total number of correctly answered questions, and the total number of incorrectly answered questions. Input validation: Only accept the letters A, B, C or D.

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] answerkey = {"b","d","a","a","c","a","a","d","b","b","b","d","c","a","c","c","a","d","a","a"};
    int n = 0;

        int correct = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;
        String answer = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter your answers. Acceptable input is limited to A,B,C and D.\n");
            answer = input.next();

            if (answer.compareTo(answerkey[0])==0){
                correct++;} 
            else {incorrect++;}
        }

        if (correct > 14){
            System.out.println("You passed.");
        } else {
           System.out.println("You failed.");
        }
        System.out.println("You have " + correct + " correct answers.");
        System.out.println("You have " + incorrect + " incorrect answers.");

}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No, actually... my question specifically (as stated in the beginning of the post) is that I don't know how to compare the given user input with the array of correct answers. For example, if the answers are [1,2,3,4,5] and the user input is [1,2,3,8,5] it should report that one element differed. What I need to know is what is a way I could do that?

Comment: Inside your for-loop if boolean check, you're hard-coding the array item checked in the answer array to be the 0th item only and not the answer item corresponding to the ith question: `if (answer.compareTo(answerkey[0])==0){`. Shouldn't it be `if (answer.compareTo(answerkey[i]) == 0) {` or `if (answer.equals(answerkey[i])) {`?

Comment: AH. Unsure how I missed that, thank you so much.

Comment: And I totally missed your question -- sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dynamic index accessing variable.  Right now, every answer you have will be compared to the first answer ("b")

An example of this would be

```
String[] myArray = { //initialize values here
                       };

for (int index = 0; index <= myArray.length-1; index++){
    if (answer.equals(myArray[index]){
        correct++;}
    else{
        incorrect++;}
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code on comparing the user input with the array `myArray`.

Hope this helps.

```
String[] myArray= { //initialize values here 
};


if ((myArray[0]).equals(answer)){
    correct++;
} else{
    incorrect++;
}
```